# "Replace capital letters in a string with "_lower case letter" and print the output" does not work

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, capitalization

For some reason following code does not work. The first part of if statement seems to work. Any ideas on what is the problem with the code?

```
sentence_input = str(input())
a = "_"
string = ""
if sentence_input.islower():
    print(sentence_input)
else:
    character_list = list(sentence_input)
    for i in character_list:
        if i.isupper():
            i.replace(i, a + i.lower())
    print(string.join(character_list))
```

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the else statement, you seem to be trying to replace the character with the new character. What you should actually be doing is replacing the element in the array altogether

try this:

```py
sentence_input = str(input())
a = "_"
string = ""
if sentence_input.islower():
    print(sentence_input)
else:
    character_list = list(sentence_input)

    for i, c in enumerate(character_list):
        if c.isupper():
            character_list[i] = "_" + c.lower()
    print(string.join(character_list))
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked!